# Fade 2 buttons with same id

Tags: jquery

I have 2 buttons with id='1'. After clicking first button, it fadesout but if i press second button it remains unchanged.

```
$("#1").click(function()
{
$("#1").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: IDs must be _unique_.

Answer (score 5):

id's should be unique if you want to fade out 2 items using the same selector use the a common class e.g.

HTML

```
<span class="fademe">Bla</span>
<span class="fademe">Bla</span>
```

JavaScript

```
$('.fademe').fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: @Jonuux you can have more than one class ... separated by space eg `class="fademe something another"` there is no limit

Answer (score 4):

You can't have two buttons with the same ID -- the browser **assumes** that IDs are unique and JavaScript will only recognize the first element with a given ID.

Soon someone will tell you that IDs can't start with a digit, either, but that was only true of HTML 4 and was rarely enforced by the browsers anyway. Still, it's considered a bad habit.

Use a common class instead:

```
$(".one").click(function() {
    $(".one").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To fade multiple things, you could use a **class**.

HTML

```
<div class="fade" id="fadeOne">Fade One</div>
<div class="fade" id="fadeTwo">Fade Two</div>

<input type="button" id="fadeButton" value="Fade" />
```

JS

```
$('#fadeButton').click(function() {
    $('.fade').fadeOut(); 
});
```

jFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/4WDV8/

**EDIT**

Man I am so slow today, Andy has it right!

Answer (score 0):

ID must be unique for each element. Try use a class instead of `id`

Try this,

```
<span id="1" class="span">Bla</span>
<span id="2" class="span">Bla</span>

$(".span").click(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut("slow");
});
```